# Copy / duplicate N times data from table A to table B In Pentaho With ETL

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I want to Copy / duplicate N times data from table A to table B in Pentaho With ETL.
the goal is to be able to fill table B as much as possible with the data from table A.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a transformation which will copy data from source table to destination table. After that you can call this transformation as many as you like.

You can look the sample from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zD9RHwZVnydNuppOptKUYZ9a7qoPXDFo?usp=sharing)